# How do I filter a reference field of an inherited mongoengine class

Tags: filtering, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Let's say I have model A, Model B and Model C

```py
class ModelA(ModelB):
    data = mongoengine.ReferenceField()

class ModelB(Document):
    customer = mongoengine.ReferenceField(ModelC)

class ModelC(Document):
    name = mongoengine.stringField()
```

I'm able to access this.
models.ModelA.objects(customer=customer)

Now I'm trying to filter where customer.name is equal to a name I pass in. Is this possible with mongoengine filters?

I tried using this method but it wont work
models.ModelA.objects(customer__name=name)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible since joins dont exist in mongodb, you need do this in 2 step, first querying the customer based on the name, then query ModelA based on the outcome of the first query.

```
customer = ModelC.objects.get(name=your_name)
ModelA.objects(customer=customer)
```